# Passing Object from a screen to another one | React-Native

Tags: javascript, android, ios, reactjs, react-native

I want to pass my data: `Info` from the screen `WebServiceUse.js` to `Cellz.js`.
I don't know how to do it, I can pass one value but not all the data..
Here's the code:

**WebServiceUse.js:**

```
export default class WebServiceUse extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = ({
            Info: [],
            isLoading: true,
            Info1: [],
        })
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        fetch('https://*****', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({ id: '1' })
        }).then((response) => response.json()).then((responseJson) => {
            this.setState({
                Info: responseJson.ed5aaf3d933385698d872d0a0d5d4f36,
                isLoading: false,
                Info1: this.Info,
            });
        }).catch((error) => {
            //console.error(error);
            alert(error);
            this.props.navigation.navigate('ScreenTwo');

        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                {this.state.isLoading &&
                    <View>
                        <ActivityIndicator color="red" size='large' animating={this.state.isLoading} />
                    </View>
                }
                <ScrollView style={styles.welcome}>
                    {
                        this.state.Info.map((item) => {
                            return (
                                <TouchableOpacity onPress={ () => (this.props.navigation.navigate('ScreenSix', {Info: item.id}))}>
                                    <Text>{item.id}</Text>
                                    <Text>{item.date}</Text>
                                    <Text>{item.interlocuteur}</Text>
                                    <View style={styles.Separator} />
                                </TouchableOpacity>
                            )
                        })
                    }
                </ScrollView>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

**Cellz.js:**

```
export default class Cellz extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);}

    render() {
        return (
            <View flexDirection='column' style={styles.container}>
                <View flexDirection='row' style={styles.welcome}>
                    <Text>ID:   </Text>
                    <Text>{this.props.navigation.state.params.Info}</Text>
                </View>
                <View flexDirection='row' style={styles.welcome}>
                    <Text>Ticket ID:    </Text>
                    <Text>{this.props.navigation.state.params.Info}</Text>
                </View>
            </View>

        );
    }
}
```

What should I do to pass all the Data `Info` ?

Comment: you are only passing item.id so you are receiving item id pass whole Info object and you will get whole object this.props.navigation.navigate('ScreenSix', {Info: this.state.Info}))

Comment: It doesn't work :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass the object if you want to,

Currently you are doing the following, which only passes the `item.id`

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={ () => (this.props.navigation.navigate('ScreenSix', {Info: item.id}))}>
```

You can pass the `item` object if you wanted, or any other object in the following way

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={ () => (this.props.navigation.navigate('ScreenSix', {Info: item.id, item: item}))}>
```

Then in your `Cellz.js`

You could get it like this

```
render() {
  const item = this.props.navigation.getParam('item');

  return (
    ...
  );
}
```

Check out the [documentation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/params.html) for more about it.